# How to get Salesforce user license details

Tags: api, licensing, salesforce

Is there a way to programmatically, through some of the existing Salesforce SOAP or RESTful APIs, get the following license details:

- type of license (enterprise, professional, developer)
- trial mode?
- trial expiration date
- is API access enabled?

...and similar.

Comment: I've tried getUserInfo() from Salesforce SOAP API. It provides license id and profile id of the user. But when you fetch the actual user's Profile and UserLicense objects, the information I need is not available. From what I've googled so far, some have scraped user's profile page to get this info, but I don't like that solution and would use it only as a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Organization](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm) object via the API. In particular the fields:

**OrganizationType**

> Edition of the organization, for example Enterprise Edition or
>   Unlimited Edition.

**TrialExpirationDate**

> The date that this organization's trial license expires.

If you try an establish an API session for a user without access enabled you will get an exception back that it isn't support. E.g. INVALID_LOGIN

You could also look at the Users [Profile](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm). Look for the fields PermissionsApiEnabled, PermissionsApiUserOnly.